# Conversion from string "Y" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: .net, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, boolean

I am learning visual basic online, however we just got a teacher switch and they have not replied to my question. So I figured I might as well ask it here. We where asked to make a computer troubleshooting program that only uses text boxes, labels, and a button. I wrote this code but when I run it I get this error "Conversion from string "Y" to type 'Boolean' is not valid." and I have no idea why or how to fix it. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub btnHelp_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
        Dim strBeep As String
        Dim strHDD As String

        strBeep = Me.txtBeep.Text
        strHDD = Me.txtHDD.Text


        If strBeep And strHDD = "Y" Then
            Me.lblMessage.Text = "Contact tech support."

        ElseIf strBeep = "Y" And strHDD = "N" Then
            Me.lblMessage.Text = "Check drive contacts."

        ElseIf strBeep And strHDD = "N" Then
            Me.lblMessage.Text = "Bring computer to repair center."

        ElseIf strBeep = "N" And strHDD = "Y" Then
            Me.lblMessage.Text = "Check the speaker connections."
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `strBeep` in an if condition without comparing it to something. This is a text and it can't be converted to `boolean`.

Do this:

```
 if strBeep = "Y" ...
```

instead of

```
 if strBeep ...
```

Complete if conditions:

```
 If strBeep = "Y" And strHDD = "Y" Then
        Me.lblMessage.Text = "Contact tech support."
 ElseIf strBeep = "Y" And strHDD = "N" Then
        Me.lblMessage.Text = "Check drive contacts."
 ElseIf strBeep = "N" And strHDD = "N" Then
        Me.lblMessage.Text = "Bring computer to repair center." 
 ElseIf strBeep = "N" And strHDD = "Y" Then
        Me.lblMessage.Text = "Check the speaker connections."
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. It would be nicer if they implemented that change as it would save time and they are both checking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to convert the strings from the text boxes at the earliest opportunity.  So rather than having Dim strBeep As String, have:

```
Dim bBeep As Boolean
Dim bHDD As Boolean

bBeep = (Me.txtBeep.Text = "Y")
bHDD = (Me.txtHDD.Text = "Y")
```

Then your if statements look like this:

```
If bBeep And bHDD Then
    'do something
Else If bBeep And Not bHDD
    'do something else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
If strBeep And strHDD = "Y" Then
```

should be

```
If strBeep = "Y" And strHDD = "Y" Then
```

`And`is a boolean operator and it's evaluated after the comparison `strHDD = "Y"` has resulted in true or false. In other words, what you're writing does not mean "if both are Y", it means if strBeep is true and strHDD is "Y" which to the compiler makes no sense since strBeep is not a true or false value.